# DNN 7.2 Advanced URL Handling

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, dotnetnuke

On My DNN 7.2.1 site I have these 2 url's that are custom to my site setup:

/.web-designers/web-designers

/.web-designers/web-designers.toulon__illinois

And I have a URL rewrite rule in my web.config:

```
<rule name="ea15b681-1192-48f3-aab7-7c17fb9db638" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^\.([^]+)/([^]+)?$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" appendQueryString="false" url="/Seo-Dummy/template/{R:1}/keywords/{R:2}" />
  </rule>
```

The url on top works as designed, the one on bottom does a 301 to:

/SEO-Dummy/template/web-designers?keywords=web-designers.toulon__illinois

I have narrowed it down to the period after web-designers.  When I replace that with a hyphen or something else, it rewrites fine without a 301.  Does anyone know why DNN 7.2 with Advanced URL handling would do this to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a fix that works for me.  I modified my redirect rule to change the redirect to :

```
/SeoDummy.aspx?template={R:1}&amp;keywords={R:2}
```

Then I added /SeoDummy.aspx to the list of "Do Not Redirect" url's in the advanced url handler.

Now all of my special url's work and give me a 200 instead of a 301.